# Document with react-styleguidist components that uses REDUX state instead of Props

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-styleguidist

I work in a React project where UI is documented using **react-styleguidist** . The project contains a few global components such as Dialogs or Panels that can be opened from many different places, so that these components are connected to Redux and I have a reducer for each where I set the state instead of receive props. This means that the components has no props.

This is an example of how I set the Dialog reducer to open the dialog with specific title and body:

```
dispatch(editDialog({
   open: true,
   title: 'Dialog title',
   body: 'Body message',
   acceptAction: 'submit',
   cancelAction: 'cancel',
}))
```

With that REDUX properties the `<Dialog />`  component will render the desired content. Since these are not props, how can I document this with react-styleguidist?
I was looking if it was possible to render a table like the one for props but to describe an object but I was unsuccessful.